# Best practice for many-to-many joins in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, many-to-many

What is the best solution for many-to-many joins in Entity Framework. It looks like in the one project where we used EF after adding the tables to the edmx file it neglected to add the intersection entity i.e.:

With these tables

```
Customer(CustomerId,...)
CustomerOrder(CustomerId,OrderId)
Order(OrderId,...)
```

The CustomerOrder table was not added to the edmx so then the tables could not be joined with a conventional (conventional meaning how we used to do it in LINQ to SQL) inner join query e.g.

```
var q = from c in db.Customers
        join co in db.CustomerOrders on c.CustomerId equals co.CustomerId
        join o in db.Orders on co.OrderId equals o.OrderId
        select a;
```

As I understand from looking at previously asked questions you could do multiple selects and "join" by specifing conditions in the where clause, or use the intersects keyword. But I would like to know what is the best practice for situations like these.

Say I would like to find out which orders a customer has, how would I go about writing that query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for clarification, when the two tables are added, the joining table is not part of the edmx, unless it contains more than just the joining table IDs.  In the scenario when EF *decides* to not use the joining table as an entity, each of the other tables *should* have navigational properties (`Orders` would have `ICollection<Customer> Customers` and `Customers` would have `ICollection<Orders>`) which allow access to the joining tables without the need to manually join them.  In that scenario you would be able to do the following:

```
var customer = dbContext.Customers.Include("Orders")
                                  .Where(o => o.Orders.OrderID == 2);
```

Normally, the navigational properties are lazy loaded, where the object(s) are not in the properties of the entity until they are accessed by code.  You can manually tell the framework to load them right away if you know you are going to use them by using the [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx) method.  This method in this example is NOT necessary in order to access the `Orders.OrderID` value.

Comment: I suspected thats the reason why that table was not included. Thanks for the answer. However if you look at the second answer on this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553918/entity-framework-and-many-to-many-queries-unusable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553918/entity-framework-and-many-to-many-queries-unusable) then it sounds like using the include keyword genereates less optimal sql code in comparison to the intersect keyword , any comment on this ?

Comment: Unless the person has either; A thoroughly tested the SQL include vs intersects or understands exactly how the SQL Optimizer works, I would doubt most peoples comments about *optimal* SQL.  The SQL Team has done an insane job increasing the optimization of SQL queries from previous versions.  Lastly, unless you plan on doing a crazy number of query updates, I wouldn't worry about how EF Generates SQL, as there are better ways to increase SQL performance than worrying about how EF Generates SQL. In my opinion, finding the *best* is academic at best.

Comment: Thanks I do agree with you it's probably me wanting perfection, when I should actually considering things like coding effort and maintainability aswell. Im marking your answer as correct, you worked for it ;) , thanx for the replies.

Comment: I feel the same way some times, it's hard to use a framework that doesn't do exactly what you want. Giving up the *perfect* code for ease of use and a little overhead is sometimes hard to swallow.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference for anyone who has similar question, I just had to see what EF actually generates and aparently EF is smart enough to add the joins where necessary when the intersection entities are hidden e.g. :

```
var query = from c in db.Clients
from o in db.Orders
where c.Id == 1 
select o.Id;
```

genereates the following sql :

```
SELECT
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM  [dbo].[Client] AS [Extent1]
CROSS JOIN [dbo].[Order] AS [Extent2]
WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[Id]
```